# What is the difference between a UIView outlet, and a ChildViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

Lets say I have a container view in a parent UIView.

What is the difference between referencing it as an Outlet in my parent UIView, or accessing it this way :

```
categoryContainerViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! CategoriesControllerView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View and view controllers are two different things 
A VIEW is an object that is drawn to the screen. It may also contain other views (subviews) that are inside it and move with it. Views can get touch events and change their visual state in response. Views are dumb, and do not know about the structure of your application, and are simply told to display themselves in some state.

A VIEW CONTROLLER is not drawable to the screen directly, it manages a group of view objects. View controllers usually have a single view with many subviews. The view controller manages the state of these views. A view controller is smart, and has knowledge of your application's inner workings. It tells the dumb view objects what to do and how to show themselves.

now you can get idea about View and a view controller.

Answer (score 1):

A view and a view controller are two totally different things.

```
categoryContainerViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! CategoriesControllerView
```

In spite of the name, that is a *view controller*.

The outlet is to the *view*.

Answer (score 1):

In layman terms : -

**IBOutlet** connects any view element from your **interface builder** to attached **swift class** file. So you can get **reference** to any subview of UIView(eg, UILabel, UIButton) from interface builder to your UIViewController or UIView Swift class

In your ex.

by using

categoryContainerViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! CategoriesControllerView

You are getting reference to your ChildViewController and not any view